# Getting the a text from EditText (but a Number)

Tags: java, android

I know that you can get a normal text like this:

```
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
String value = input.getText().toString();
```

but now I need a to an input like this: 0xFFFFFF (a Hex-Color), an Integer... But value is only a String and I don't know how to convert it... I'm using view.setBackgroundColor(color);

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if I am not mistaken, `view.setBackgroundColor(color)` will work when you have `color = input.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Color.parseColor(colorString);` function to convert your string to a color int